# Creating 2 slicers from the same column with different values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

i have created a pivot table from a single column like the one below and basically i want to create two slicers for that column showing two different sets of data in that column.for example, i want a slicer to have values,A,B,C and the other one to have D,E,F,G .Was wondering if anyone has done anything similar.

Thank you all for the help

```
|Column1|
|   A   |
|   B   |
|   C   |
|   D   |
|   E   |
|   F   |
|   G   |
```